# How to have Curl_Multi_Exec return more than 20 good requests without having 500 error code

Tags: php, curl, zend-framework, curl-multi

I'm currently in the process of creating a script that will send a large number of Urls to the Google Pagespeed Insights API (under the specified 100 per user per 100 seconds), process the returned information, and have the scores added to my database tables accordingly.

My problem arises when I attempt to send more than 20 using Curl_multi_exec, as any amount of requests over this amount will send back 500 error responses littered throughout, so that there are only 20 good requests with info (400 code responses).

I believe I am far below what i'm allowed to process at a time with this API. I have already attempted with modifying my php.ini 'max_file_uploads' field so that it was greater than 20; however, this did not remedy the issue.

My code is as follows:

```
    $results = array();

    $pagespeedInsightsUrls = new PagespeedInsightsUrls();
    $pagespeedUris = $pagespeedInsightsUrls->getPagespeedInsightsUrls();

   $cSession = curl_multi_init();

   for($i = 0; $i <= 29; $i++ ) {

    $curly[$i] = curl_init();

    $pagespeedURL = $googlePagespeedURL .$domains['common']. $pagespeedUris[$i]['pagespeed_urls'] . $strategy[0] . $apiKeys['TEST'];
    curl_setopt($curly[$i], CURLOPT_URL, $pagespeedURL);
    curl_setopt($curly[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_multi_add_handle($cSession, $curly[$i]);
   }
   $running = null;

   do {
      curl_multi_exec($cSession, $running); 
   } while($running > 0);

   foreach($curly as $i => $c) {
      $results[$i] = curl_multi_getcontent($c); 
      curl_multi_remove_handle($cSession, $c);
   }

   curl_multi_close($cSession);
```

With this, I would receive 10 500 codes littered throughout the 20 'good' requests. This is a script being ran in a Zend_framework environment.

Would anybody have any idea of where to start looking for a fix on this? The documentation for Curl_Multi is severely lacking.

Comment: 500 spells server `error`.  You are probably exceeding some kind of quota ... i doubt this is a curl'ish issue.

Comment: Thats also what I initially thought; however, google has its request limits stated as '25000 per day', and '100 per 100 seconds per user'. Could it possibly be any sort of settings on my end that are preventing me from recieving the data? or does Curl_Multi_Exec have some sort of timeout period. It is taking the expected amount of time to receive the response, its just that its busted.

Comment: doubt it ... they could have an 'app enforced' rate limiter. If i understand your code, all sessions will be initiated at `close to the same time`.  That would trigger any in-app intrusion detection. (just a WAG here, but since you are getting 500's i doubt this is net-enforced).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Google's API server limits to 20 simultaneous connections.  At your end, Curl is implementing these concurrent requests not by multiplexing over a single connection but by performing each in its own connection, requiring a connection for each request.  It is fairly normal for HTTP servers to reject more than a handful of simultaneous connections per IP, though in this case it looks like Google has implemented the limit at the HTTP server level because it is accepting the connection but returning a 500 error.

Any limit on the number of simultaneous connections is a separate limit to their maximum number of requests per day or per 100 seconds.

According to [their site](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/limits-quotas), you aren't supposed to exceed 10 concurrent requests *per view*.  If you are getting 20, then either Google is being more tolerant in what they accept than they state or your code is sending requests for 2 different views, or some other reason.